Thermal flunctuations of density in thermal equlibrium?
According to physics a fluid or gas in thermal equilibrium is not exactly homogeneous. Locally its density undergoes random fluctuations which are small compared to the corresponding equilibrium value.
Is there some formula or bibliography that describes these thermal fluctuations and their dependance on temperature?

Standard courses of statistical physics typically discuss fluctuations, deriving that their magnitude behaves as $\sim 1/\sqrt{N}$. Density fluctuations might not be discussed specifically... but they are easily obtained from the particle number fluctuations (dividing by the volume of the gas). I suggest reviewing these and making the question more specific.

You are either looking for fluctuating hydrodynamics or to classical density functional theory.
